# CSV Export Automatically converting value of functionally created text version of SQL date format, from filemaker standard to something weird

Tags: excel, csv, filemaker

i have exported a .CSV from filemaker so i can import the .CSV into a MySQL database. The issue i am getting is that the CSV is automatically thinking that the data is some form of custom formatting and then turns the data into something completely wrong. But that's not the most stupid part, i can click inside the formula bar and see THE FREAKING VALUE I EXPORTED. i have tried to format the cells and it doesn't seem to do much for me, but i noticed that if i manually prepend a "'" into the formula bar it will work. i just really dont want to do that 4300 times for ~6 fields, so do any of you have any ideas what went wrong, or how to fix it?

Heres an example:
12:16:42 AM turns into 16:42.0

Comment: Are you opening SCV file in Excel? This will try to auto-add custom formatting and guess data types. Try to open in a text editor

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with either MySQL or FileMaker.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the value is coming from filemaker, so i was seeing if anyone else who was doing this ran into the same issue, and this has nothing to do with SQL, whoever marc_s is added SQL to the tags, i didn't have it on there.

Comment: @Nicolai i was using excel to open the file, i just ended up working around this and exported the file as a .xlsx and then copied the values over, and it worked. But i would rather not have to do that tedious process to change the values. the reason i opened the .CSV in excel was so i could add formatting to the column in order to quote all long strings

Comment: I understand from your description that the export from FileMaker to .csv works as expected. Once you have the .csv file, it stands on its own and its origin bears no relevance to the problem of how it's read by Excel. -- P.S. If you want to get your data into Excel, export as Excel. If you want to get your data into MySQL (or any other target application) do not go through Excel.